# Merge 2 arrays in alternating order in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 2 arrays which need to be merged in alternating order.

[image]

Result is a VBA array.

Comment: Why do you need VBA? Is the end result a VBA array, or results in a worksheet?

Comment: @BigBen Edited my question, Ben. It's a VBA array.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where it fails.

Comment: Do you understand the VBA array concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was bored.  It is a matter of iterating the arrays and filling a third:

```
Sub mergit()
    Dim arr1 As Variant
    arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    
    Dim arr2 As Variant
    arr2 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
    
    Dim arr3 As Variant
    ReDim arr3(0 To UBound(arr1) + UBound(arr2) + 1)
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = 0
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        arr3(k) = arr1(i)
        arr3(k + 1) = arr2(i)
        k = k + 2
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print Join(arr3, ",")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm